# WPF DataGrid two-way source binding to List<DataClass> programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, runtime

I need do the binding at run time since the DataGrid will be bound to different data sources and/or class objects. I have two classes CA and CB. In CB, there is a method to set up binding. But the simple way below only sets one way binding. How to do two-way binding? I.E. when an element in `List<CA>` list changed, the DataGrid1 will automatically updated.

```
class CA
{
    private int a = 1;
    private string b = "";
    private bool c = true;
    public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
    public string B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
    public bool C { get { return c; } set { c = value; } }
}

class CB
{
    List<CA> datalist = new List<CA>();
    private void SetBinding(ref List<CA> ca, ref DataGrid dg)
    {
        dg.ItemsSource = ca;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is also important to note that you should not be passing ca or dg as ref, unless you have some very compelling reason to do so (I cannot imagine one.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to be bound correctly, your class CA should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx
And all the properties should raise the propertyChanged event to notify databound controls.

Here you can find simple example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

Also, I'd recommend using ObservableCollection instead of List with databinding, since it has INotifyPropertyChanged out of the box and notifies databound control of elements additions, deletions and changes.

Comment: You beat me to it, but just to clarify, using ObservableCollection still means the OP needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on CA.

Comment: Of course, there's no tracking changes on individual properties of random object

Answer (score 1):

Your class "CA" will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for changes to the CA objects to be reflected in your datagrid.

If you also want the datagrid to be aware of items being added and removed then you will need to use an ObservableCollection instead of List or at least a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.